# Is it possible to create a directive for a dynamic template?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <div partial="note"></div>
    <div partial="controls"></div>
</ul>
```

Where the `partial` attribute specifies which template to use for the element.  The directive allowing this to be possible would be like:

```
.directive('partial', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/partials/' + attrs.partial + '.html'
    }
})
```

The only thing is, I don't know how to get that `attrs` object there where it needs to be.  I tried injecting it in various ways, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1039

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-include directive for that.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude